# Using Mediator to call async method from within a data-bound property setter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-community-toolkit

I need to call an async method `ConnectToLibrary` once a book is selected, meaning once `SelectedBook` property is set. I saw many solutions. But all of them require hacks or starting a task/thread from a setter. My question, what's wrong with using a mediator like `Messenger` from Microsoft Toolkit.Mvvm?

I can just register a callback to `ConnectToLibrary` with `Messenger.Register<...BookSelectedMessage>(...ConnectToLibrary...)`  and then call `Messenger.Send(new BookSelectedMessage())` from the `SelectedBook`'s setter.

Is this the correct way to do this in MVVM?

```
public MyViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    public ObservableCollection<BookInfo> Books { get; } = new();    

    private BookInfo _selectedBook;
    public BookInfo SelectedBook
    {
        get => _selectedBook;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedBook, value);
    }

    private async Task ConnectToLibrary(BookInfo info)
    {        
        await START_SOME_ASYNC_METHOD();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Is this the correct way to do this in MVVM?"_ - MVVM is only concerned with the notion of binding a markup template-based view to an observable object (i.e. binding XAML to a ViewModel) that models only the busines/domain part of the view (hence the name: View-Model) - everything else about the wider architecture of a software application is entirely up to you.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example - whenever the property SearchTerm changes an async request is made (well it is a little bit smarter with the throtteling)

Comment: You should ask yourself this; How do you verify that `ConnectToLibrary` gets called as expected in a unit test? If you can mock the messenger, set the property and verify that the `ConnectToLibrary`/`START_SOME_ASYNC_METHOD` was indeed called, you are fine as fas as MVVM is concerned. Properties should generally speaking not kick off asynchronous operations though.

Comment: @mm8, if "properties should generally not kick off asynchronous operations", what is the better approach?

Comment: Call the method directly? Or use a command.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing. In either case any `Exception` is swallowed. And since you are asking, what's wrong with starting a thread from a `Setter`? It sounds to me like the requirements of your app require this anyway, no?